# databricks configure using cmd and R

Tags: r, command-line, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to use databricks cli and invoke the databricks configure 
That's how I do it from cmd

```
  somepath>databricks configure --token
  Databricks Host (should begin with https://): my_https_address 
  Token: my_token
```

I want to invoke the same command using R. So I did:

```
  tool.control <- c('databricks configure --token'
                    ,'my_https_address'
                    ,'my_token')

 shell(tool.control)
```

I get the following error

```
  Error in system(command, as.integer(flag), f, stdout, stderr, timeout) : 
  character string expected as first argument
```

How can I correct it?

EDIT:
After trying the suggestion in the comment, I get this error:

```
Databricks Host (should begin with https://): Aborted!
'https:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
 'my_token' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1

Warning messages:
 1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
 'databricks configure --token' execution failed with error code 1
 2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
  'my_https_address' execution failed with error code 1
 3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
 'my_token' execution failed with error code 1
```

Comment: `lapply(tool.control, shell)`.

Comment: I get some error after trying your suggestion. I have edited the question to show the errors. Thanks