# How can I download a file from blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks

I have a CSV file in my blob storage.  I want to download the file.  The weird things is, I can't actually see the file.  The file CSV is created by a Python job and converted into a Scala dataframe.

When I run these 2 lines of code:

```
# convert python df to spark df and export the spark df
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
## Write Frame out as Table
spark_df.write.csv("dbfs:/rawdata/corp/AAA.csv")
```

I get this error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: path dbfs:/rawdata/corp/AAA.csv already exists.;
```

The weird thing is that I can't see the file when I'm using Azure Storage Explorer.  Apparently the file exists, even though I can't see it.  How can I download this CSV file?  I would like to use Databricks, preferably, or maybe something else, if someone here can suggest a better option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** Using GUI, you can download full results (max 1 millions rows).

[image]

To download full results (more than 1 million), first save the file to dbfs and then copy the file to local machine using Databricks cli as follows.

> dbfs cp "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/AA.csv" "A:\AzureAnalytics"

**Reference:** [Databricks file system](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html)

The DBFS command-line interface (CLI) uses the DBFS API to expose an easy to use command-line interface to DBFS. Using this client, you can interact with DBFS using commands similar to those you use on a Unix command line. For example:

```
# List files in DBFS
dbfs ls
# Put local file ./apple.txt to dbfs:/apple.txt
dbfs cp ./apple.txt dbfs:/apple.txt
# Get dbfs:/apple.txt and save to local file ./apple.txt
dbfs cp dbfs:/apple.txt ./apple.txt
# Recursively put local dir ./banana to dbfs:/banana
dbfs cp -r ./banana dbfs:/banana
```

**Reference:** [Installing and configuring Azure Databricks CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867156/databricks-configure-using-cmd-and-r/57992044#57992044)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are exactly right.  I just figured this out a few days back.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the blob storage [sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) and the following command

```
# Download as a file
block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path(container_name, blob_name, local_file_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another nice solution here.

https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html

[image]

Just before this step, do display the contents of a dataframe, run this line of code.

```
display(df)
```