# Download files (databricks/driver)

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I tried to download an excel file that I generated via pandas but I can't find it ... I know it is in the file:/databricks/driver but I can download it ...

Is it possible to transfer it into storage or transfer it to my machine local?

I tried it but it didn't work.

```
dbutils.fs.cp('file:/databricks/driver/test.xlsx','dbfs:/mnt/datalake/test.xlsx')
```

Comment: Works for me with:
dbutils.fs.cp("file:/databricks/driver/myfile.js","dbfs:/FileStore/myfile.js")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** Using Databricks GUI, you can download full results (max 1 millions rows).

[image]

**OR**

**Using Databricks CLI:**

To download full results (more than 1 million), first save the file to dbfs and then copy the file to local machine using **Databricks CLI** as follows.

> dbfs cp "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/AA.csv" "A:\AzureAnalytics"

**Reference:** [Databricks file system](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html)

The DBFS command-line interface (CLI) uses the DBFS API to expose an easy to use command-line interface to DBFS. Using this client, you can interact with DBFS using commands similar to those you use on a Unix command line. For example:

```
# List files in DBFS
dbfs ls
# Put local file ./apple.txt to dbfs:/apple.txt
dbfs cp ./apple.txt dbfs:/apple.txt
# Get dbfs:/apple.txt and save to local file ./apple.txt
dbfs cp dbfs:/apple.txt ./apple.txt
# Recursively put local dir ./banana to dbfs:/banana
dbfs cp -r ./banana dbfs:/banana
```

**Reference:** [Installing and configuring Azure Databricks CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867156/databricks-configure-using-cmd-and-r/57992044#57992044)

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.