# Error in Databricks Selenium "WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application Stacktrace:"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, azure-databricks

I am trying to do webscraping using Selenium in Chrome within Azure Databricks. Please find the below code.

```
%pip install selenium
%pip install webdriver_manager

from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ExpectedConditions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Specify the path to the uploaded chromedriver file
chrome_driver_path = '/dbfs/FileStore/Chromedriver/chromedriver'
chrome_service = Service(chrome_driver_path)

# Configure Chrome options
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application"

options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode (without GUI)
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

# Create a new Chrome webdriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=options)

# Example usage: Open a website and print the page title
url = "https://data.cms.gov/tools/mapping-medicare-disparities-by-population"
driver.get(url)


# Clean up and quit the webdriver
driver.quit()
```

However I am getting below error -
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
Stacktrace:

Comment: Databricks is a cloud application, you cannot refer to a local folder on your computer (c:\.program files\)

Comment: @ChenHirsh Thanks. Then how can I specify the Binary location of chrome ? Should the Binary be added to dbfs i.e. delta lake ?

Comment: @Abishek, that should probably be the way to go. I found this answer with details steps, hope it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67830079/how-to-use-selenium-in-databricks-and-accessing-and-moving-downloaded-files-to-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
```

[image]

Using shell command save the chromedriver version 113 in
`/tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip`.

```
%sh
wget  -N https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/113.0.5672.63/chromedriver_linux64.zip -O /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip
```

Unzip the file.

[image]

```
%sh
unzip /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /tmp/chromedriver113/
```

Install chrome version 113.

```
%sh
sudo  curl  -sS  -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add
sudo  echo  "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
```

[image]

Know get the data from url.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('/tmp/chromedriver113/chromedriver'), options=options)
url = "https://data.cms.gov/tools/mapping-medicare-disparities-by-population"
browser.get(url)
browser.title
```

[image]

Follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67830079/how-to-use-selenium-in-databricks-and-accessing-and-moving-downloaded-files-to-m) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @JayashankarGS. Did you tried this on Databricks ?

Comment: Yes. I have executed in databricks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
%pip install selenium
%pip install webdriver_manager

from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ExpectedConditions
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

# Create a new Chrome webdriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options= options)

url = "https://data.cms.gov/tools/mapping-medicare-disparities-by-population"
driver.get(url)

driver.quit()
```

The issue with your code is that you are pointing the chrome driver to a Windows path (C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application), which of course does not exist in the Databricks workspace.

Comment: I am getting error on below line                                                                               
# Create a new Chrome webdriver instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options= options)                                                                                                                                 Error - WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Comment: The webdriver_manager library was supposed to get the binaries for you. Are you using it? Here you can find more details on the lib: https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/