# Chrome driver issue in data bricks

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, azure-databricks, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am facing Web driver exception while running below code.
Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#print(driver.service.executable_path)
chrome_options= Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.binary_location = "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromedriver_binary/chromedriver"  # Replace with the actual path to your Chrome binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
print(driver.service.process.path)
```

Error:

```
ebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromedriver_binary/chromedriver is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

below are the libraries installed on cluster:
[image]

have tried multiple things and tried to download manually chrome and driver but still no luck. After that have tried to do using firefox but for that getting below issue. Please suggest how to achieve this problem.

Firefox code:

```
%sh 
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz -O /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz

%sh
tar -xvzf /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz -C /tmp

%sh
ls /tmp/gec*

%sh 
/usr/bin/yes | sudo apt update --fix-missing > /dev/null 2>&1

%sh 
sudo apt-get --yes --force-yes install firefox > /dev/null 2>&1

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options =Options()
options.headless =True
driver=webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path ='/tmp/geckodriver')
```

Error :

```
<command-1051731704975926>:6: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver=webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path ='/tmp/geckodriver')
WebDriverException: Message: Service /tmp/geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

Comment: See if this helps you [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76355603/error-in-databricks-selenium-webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-no-chr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can follow this approach.

Run below code for setting up options.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
binary_path = "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/chromedriver_binary/chromedriver"
```

Next, run below for installing stable chrome version.

```
%sh
sudo  curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add
sudo  echo  "deb https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
```

[image]

Here, you can see the chrome version is **114.0.5735**, it is same with the chromebinary you installed in cluster.

[image]

Then, get the browser object.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(binary_path), options=options)
print(browser.service.process.args)
```

[image]