WebDriverException: Message: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure
I'm trying to connect to Selenium through databricks.
We've been facing a problem while creating the webdriver:
WebDriverException: Message: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure

The code we're currently using is this:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server={getProxy()['http']}")

chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

# Set up ChromeDriver service
chrome_service = Service('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)

# Navigate to a webpage
driver.get("http://www.google.com")

# Print the title of the page
print(driver.title)

# Close the driver
driver.quit()

We've also tried to use os.envirom to set the proxies instead of using the Selenium Options() class.
We're expecting the driver to connect to chrome.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67830079/how-to-use-selenium-in-databricks-and-accessing-and-moving-downloaded-files-to-m
