# I am trying to use databricks cli and invoke the databricks configure

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-cli

I am trying to use databricks CLI and invoke the databricks configure. At the point where we need to enter the token,I am neither able to type anything or copy paste anything.

Comment: If it is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? It may help more people who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to just copy the token and paste and hit enter.

**Note:** Even after pasting the token it will show as blank.

[image].

Now you can run the `databricks fs ls` command to check whether you have successfully configured.

[image]

For more details, refer similar thread: [databricks configure using cmd and R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867156/databricks-configure-using-cmd-and-r/57992044#57992044)

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.