# Azure Databricks - Export and Import DBFS filesystem

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

We have just created a new Azure Databricks resource into our resource group. In the same resource group there is an old instance of Azure Databricks. Starting from this old Databricks instance, I would copy the data stored in dbfs into the newest Databricks instance.
How could I do that? My idea is to use FS commands in order to copy or move data from a dbfs to another, probably mounting the volumes, but I am not getting how could I do that.
Do you have any indications?

Thanks,
Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately, there is no direct method to export and import files/folders from one workspace to another workspace.

**Note:** It's is highly recommended: **Do not Store any Production Data in Default DBFS Folders**

[image]

> How to copy files/folders from one workspace to another workspace?

You need to manually download files/folders from one workspace and upload files/folders to another workspace.

The easiest way is to using DBFS Explorer:

[image]

[image]

Click this link to view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/umF9y.jpg

> Download file/folder from DBFS to the local machine:

**Method1: Using Databricks CLI**

The DBFS command-line interface (CLI) uses the DBFS API to expose an easy to use command-line interface to DBFS. Using this client, you can interact with DBFS using commands similar to those you use on a Unix command line. For example:

```
# List files in DBFS
dbfs ls
# Put local file ./apple.txt to dbfs:/apple.txt
dbfs cp ./apple.txt dbfs:/apple.txt
# Get dbfs:/apple.txt and save to local file ./apple.txt
dbfs cp dbfs:/apple.txt ./apple.txt
# Recursively put local dir ./banana to dbfs:/banana
dbfs cp -r ./banana dbfs:/banana
```

Reference: [Installing and configuring Azure Databricks CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867156/databricks-configure-using-cmd-and-r/57992044#57992044) and [Azure Databricks – Access DBFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#access-dbfs)

**Method2: Using third-party tool named DBFS Explorer**

[DBFS Explorer](https://datathirst.net/projects/dbfs-explorer) was created as a quick way to upload and download files to the Databricks filesystem (DBFS). This will work with both AWS and Azure instances of Databricks. You will need to create a bearer token in the web interface in order to connect.

[image]

> Upload file/folder from the local machine to DBFS:

There are multiple ways to upload files from a local machine to the Azure Databricks DBFS folder.

**Method1: Using the Azure Databricks portal.**

[image]

**Method2: Using Databricks CLI**

The DBFS command-line interface (CLI) uses the DBFS API to expose an easy to use command-line interface to DBFS. Using this client, you can interact with DBFS using commands similar to those you use on a Unix command line. For example:

```
# List files in DBFS
dbfs ls
# Put local file ./apple.txt to dbfs:/apple.txt
dbfs cp ./apple.txt dbfs:/apple.txt
# Get dbfs:/apple.txt and save to local file ./apple.txt
dbfs cp dbfs:/apple.txt ./apple.txt
# Recursively put local dir ./banana to dbfs:/banana
dbfs cp -r ./banana dbfs:/banana
```

[image]

**Method3: Using third-party tool named DBFS Explorer**

DBFS Explorer was created as a quick way to upload and download files to the Databricks filesystem (DBFS). This will work with both AWS and Azure instances of Databricks. You will need to create a bearer token in the web interface in order to connect.

**Step1:** Download and install DBFS Explorer and install it.

**Step2**: Open DBFS Explorer and Enter: Databricks URL and Personal Access Token

[image]

**Step3:** Select the folder where you want to upload the files from the local machine and just drag and drop in the folder to upload and click upload.

[image]

Comment: Thanks CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT! In the meanwhile I have manually synced within CLI, but I would try the DBFS Explorer tool for next challenges!