# Databricks - Download a dbfs:/FileStore file to my Local Machine

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Normally I use below URL to download file from Databricks DBFS FileStore to my local computer.

```
*https://<MY_DATABRICKS_INSTANCE_NAME>/fileStore/?o=<NUMBER_FROM_ORIGINAL_URL>*
```

However, this time the file is not downloaded and the URL lead me to Databricks homepage instead.
Does anyone have any suggestion on how I can download file from DBFS to local area? or how should fix the URL to make it work?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

PJ

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> **Method1:** Using Databricks portal GUI, you can download full results (max 1 millions rows).

[image]

> **Method2:** Using Databricks CLI

To download full results, first save the file to dbfs and then copy the file to local machine using Databricks cli as follows.

```
dbfs cp "dbfs:/FileStore/tables/my_my.csv" "A:\AzureAnalytics"
```

You can access DBFS objects using the DBFS CLI, DBFS API, Databricks file system utilities (dbutils.fs), Spark APIs, and local file APIs.

In a Spark cluster you access DBFS objects using Databricks file system utilities, Spark APIs, or local file APIs.

On a local computer you access DBFS objects using the **Databricks CLI** or **DBFS API**.

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks – Access DBFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#access-dbfs)

The DBFS command-line interface (CLI) uses the DBFS API to expose an easy to use command-line interface to DBFS. Using this client, you can interact with DBFS using commands similar to those you use on a Unix command line. For example:

```
# List files in DBFS
dbfs ls
# Put local file ./apple.txt to dbfs:/apple.txt
dbfs cp ./apple.txt dbfs:/apple.txt
# Get dbfs:/apple.txt and save to local file ./apple.txt
dbfs cp dbfs:/apple.txt ./apple.txt
# Recursively put local dir ./banana to dbfs:/banana
dbfs cp -r ./banana dbfs:/banana
```

**Reference:** [Installing and configuring Azure Databricks CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867156/databricks-configure-using-cmd-and-r/57992044#57992044)

> **Method3:** Using third-party tool named DBFS Explorer

[DBFS Explorer](https://github.com/DataThirstLtd/DBFS-Explorer) was created as a quick way to upload and download files to the Databricks filesystem (DBFS). This will work with both AWS and Azure instances of Databricks. You will need to create a bearer token in the web interface in order to connect.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion!
Method 3 is very convenient.

Comment: method 1 won't work for data where column has some struct type like json string.